# Get specific contents from CURL request

Tags: php, curl

I am attempting to grab a Song Title and Artist from a Spotify URI

Currently -> *Grabs USER ID and Playlist ID* -> Creates an Embedded Playlist -> *Spits out entire playlist*

[RESULT from Embedded playlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cJY9f.png)

What I'm really trying to do is almost print a LIST of the songs in plain text. I wish to avoid the Spotify API as much as possible

--  index.php

```
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="_/css/style.css" />
<script src="_/js/inputcheck.js"></script>
<body>

<section id="outPopUp">
    <form name="myForm" class="input-list style-1 clearfix" action="get_playlist.php" onsubmit="return validateForm()" method="get">
    Spotify URI to MP3:
    <input type="text" name="uri"><br>
    <input class="myButton" type="submit">

</section>
</body>
</html>
```

--    get_playlist.php

```
<?php

$uri = $_GET['uri'];

// Match exact Spotify playlist URI pattern
if ($c=preg_match_all("/".'(spotify)'.'(:)'.'(user)'.'(:)'.'((?:[A-Za-z0-9_-]*))'.'(:)'.'(playlist)'.'(:)'.'((?:[A-Za-z0-9]*))'."/is", $uri, $matches)) {
    $userID = $matches[5][0];
    $playlistID = $matches[9][0];
} else {
echo 'Error: Could not parse URI. Script needs ?uri= with the Spotify playlist URI.';
die;
}

$url = "https://embed.spotify.com/?uri=spotify:user:".$userID.":playlist:".$playlistID."&output=json";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; curl)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
$embeddedplayer = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $embeddedplayer;

?>
```

If anyone could help, that would be fabulous

Comment: Why avoid the Spotify API?

Comment: NODE.js has been screwing with my mind all day

Comment: https://github.com/jwilsson/spotify-web-api-php

Comment: LOL. Why do not use the PHP library, as Jigar published here?

Comment: they have an API - USE IT